# Mouse not listed in pointing device list in the device manager

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, drivers, mouse

I'm trying to debug the laptop of one of my friend. It's running Windows 8.1.
The model is an ASUS X751DL

The external (usb plugged) mouse is not working anymore. It is a wireless (usb dungle) Trust mouse. When I plug it to the USB 3.0 slot it is not listed in the pointing devices list in the device manager. The usual "unrecognized device" windows message when an issue is detected is NOT appearing.

I tried to plug the mouse on the 3 different USB 3.0 ports => Same issue.
I tried to plug wire mouses (3 other different ones) => same issue.
I launched windows in safe mode => same issue.

I checked the BIOS: Legacy USB support is **enabled**.

I plugged other USB devices (USB key, cell phone) => all of them are working perfectly. We can forget a HW issue with the laptop USB ports.

I tried the mouse on another laptop (windows 7) and it is working like a charm. So we can also forget a mouse HW issue.

I looked up in the "Event collector" to see if I could find something that could explain this issue. I just found a "A pointer device reported a bad angular physical range" but don't really know how it can be linked to my current issue.

My guess is that somehow Windows blacked list the mouse and prevents it to be listed. But I've never been confronted to such an issue.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Does the mouse have drivers?

Comment: USB 3 ports (and driver stuff) have to have a 2.0 compatability hub thing that shows in the devices , you should be able to see when you list the devices by connection (view - device by connection) If that isnt there, then you either need the proper USB 3.0 driver , or something is slightly amiss about the usb 3.0 driver set, complicated by the backward compatability need.   With notes that it doesnt always make total sence how it is laid out in the connections, just that you should be able to discover by viewing by connection.

Comment: RACING121: No, there is no driver for any of my mice.
Psychogeek: I discovered where the mouse is enumerated, it's in the "User interface devices" (translation from French). I got two drivers listed: "USB entry device" and "HID-compliant device". And nothing is enumerated in the pointing device list excepted the touch pad. I'm not able to reinstall the USB 3.0 drivers. I got the message "The Asmedia USB Host controller was not found". I changed a couple of parameters in the BIOS to enable USB 3.0 but it didn't work...

Comment: Based on windows 7 there should be a "controller" host controller, then the compatability hub, then the HID or Input device. So you kind of confirmed that there is something wrong with the driver stuff. any further help we would have to know the model of computer or motherboard or something to see what drivers would work.  Are you getting the drivers direct from the source? , from the manufactures site for the model of computer?  The web is Full of driver sites that will point to the wrong things or even have malware for the downloads.  You can check the manuel (often) for the audio chip used.

Comment: @Psycogeek: The laptop is an ASUS X751DL. I got the drivers from Asus web site itself for Windows 8.1 64bits. There was a strange driver package installed 6 months before my friend bought the Laptop (new) from her store. That means this PC had certainly been returned from the previous owner after sale. The name of the package "Windows Driver Package - ASUS (ATP) Mouse". Meaning that there was certainly already an issue with the mouse recognition.

Comment: Precision: without this package the touchepad is not working anymore. I checked on Asus web site and didn't find anything about this strange package that can be found only on doubtful sites...